# Convert different DateTime Strings to single DateTime format using C#

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-format

I am created one browser extension which is installed in all major browsers. After installation is complete I will get the date time from that related browser to my application, what my problem is datetime format is different for different browsers like below

Chrome : 
4/10/2014 1:06:49 PM

Firefox and IE :
Thursday, April 10, 2014 1:14:00 PM

Safari:
Wednesday, April 23, 2014 14:00:17 PM

I need to convert those all different string format datetime to single datetime format, currently I am using the below code it is working good for chrome datetime format but not for remaining formats

```
 public bool CompareInsertTimes(string strPluginDatetime)
    {
DateTime pluginModifyDate;            
 pluginModifyDate = DateTime.ParseExact(strPluginDatetime, "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

"strPluginDatetime" is the datetime string from chrome,firefox,IE,safari
Then I am using below format to compare datetime format to my database datetime

```
Convert.ToDateTime(pluginModifyDate.GetDateTimeFormats()[28]) < Convert.ToDateTime(urlModifydateinDB.GetDateTimeFormats()[28])
```

So, is there any possibility to convert different string format datetimes to single datetime format

Comment: Have you looked at the overload for `DateTime.ParseExact` which takes multiple formats? Where are you getting the string from anyway? There may be cleaner options.

Comment: You're better-off getting the date-time value in the right format at the source. Can't your browser-extension get the current UTC date/time  in ISO-8061 format or UNIX timestamp somehow?

Comment: So, is "4/10/2014 1:06:49 PM" the 4th of October or the 10th of April? It depends where you are. Unless you figure out a way of resolving the ambiguity, it's going to be a tricky task.

Comment: @spender: I don't see the "ambiguity" since OP has already mentioned that his code works for chrome which has your sample date. OP is using `M/d/yyyy`. So imho it's obvious that it's 10th of April, isn't it?

Comment: @TimSchmelter: I'm sure it "works on his machine" ;)

Comment: @spender: i cannot fix an issue which does not yet exist so i presume that OP knows what he does and that the date formats + culture are fixed.

Answer (score -1):

This works for all:

```
string[] dateStrings = { "4/10/2014 1:06:49 PM", "Thursday, April 10, 2014 1:14:00 PM", "Wednesday, April 23, 2014 14:00:17 PM"};
string[] formats = { "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", "dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy h:mm:ss tt", "dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss tt" };
DateTime[] dates = new DateTime[dateStrings.Length];
for(int i = 0; i < dateStrings.Length; i++)
{
    DateTime dt;
    bool ok = DateTime.TryParseExact(dateStrings[i], formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt);
    if (ok) dates[i] = dt;
}
```

Test:

```
Console.Write(string.Join(", ", dates));
```

Output:

```
10.04.2014 13:06:49, 10.04.2014 13:14:00, 23.04.2014 14:00:17
```

Comment: I'm not 100% convinced that CultureInfo.InvariantCulture is right: I haven't checked this but would have expected the browsers to use the current user's regional settings.  In any case, make sure you test on browsers in different cultures.

Comment: Good point, then op should pass null or CulturInfo.CurrentCulture. But since op also used InvariantCulture and I don't know exactly from where the dates are I leave it as it is.